# Examples of a city or region with poor economy and environmental pollution that turned to green economy and prospered

Tags: pollution, economy

I am looking for some examples of cities or regions that initially suffered from poor economy, unemployment, pollution or any environmental problems, but they turned to green technology and environmental friendly businesses that lead to job creations and turn around in that region.

I need these examples to make them into projects for some middle schoolers. The examples need to be from real life and concrete so the student can do their own research and in the process learn how to think differently and apply it to other cases.

Comment: Pittsburgh mostly lost heavy industry but then developed service industries. They didn't have a goal of getting rid of heavy pollution but just lost it. They did have some early projects of cleaning the air and the rivers but heavy industry was still running at that time.

Comment: Thank you, S Spring. Pittsburg is a good example. Do you know any small rural areas or small cities that did something similar?

Comment: Costa Rica comes to mind -- a lot of agricultural areas turned to ecotourism. Also the island of Ometepe in Nicaragua.

Comment: Thank you @LShaver.